# ListView is not displaying in a usual way

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I want to display a list of data, some data contains values and others contains null value. I don't want to show the null values in this list.

For that I have written the following code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attachment_adapter, parent, false);

    TextView attachment = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.attachment_text);
    attach = list.get(position);

    if(attach.recording_path.equals("null")){
        rowView.findViewById(R.id.attachment_text).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    else{
        attachment.setText(attach.recording_path);
    }

}
```

But when I run it on a device it is not looking usual.

[image]

Comment: update your array before set data  to adapter.like remove all null values from your array and set data to adapter.

Comment: @Ram But am checking null values only in adapter. How to do that before setting to the adapter

Comment: try setting instead: `rowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` if it's not working, maybe it's caused by the divider between the listview items

Comment: it looks like you have a separator between your items, so if you hide one its separator is still visible

Comment: I guesss it has to do with `getCount()` method

Comment: @aschattney yes it is working. And empty item's also visible without null

Comment: @user3764346: you should implement the suggestion from Ram which will definitely prevent this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attachment_adapter, parent, false);
    TextView attachment = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.attachment_text);
    attach = list.get(position);
    
   if(attach.recording_path != null)
    {
        attachment.setText(attach.recording_path);
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below conditional statements

```
if(attach.recording_path!=null))
{
    attachment.setText(attach.recording_path);
}
```

And Remove else condition 
  Thankx
if any query then you can ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Stop Adding that recording_path To your arrayList first of all.

or else stop Loading null data to your model

Answer (score 0):

You should delete wrong values from list before you set it in adapter.
Adapter shouldn't filter data in any way.